# Laravel 5.2 unknown column when selecting from database table

Tags: mysql, sql, web, laravel-5

I've just started learning laravel last week, and this error occured when I tried to access a row using it's id, the id is fetched from the url.

QueryException in Connection.php line 725:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'berita.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `berita` where `berita`.`id` = 7 limit 1)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkH75.png)

I know you must be thinking that I don't have "id" column, yes I don't. But I have "id_berita" column which I wrote in the code instead of "id".

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('edit/{id_berita}', 'RecordsController@edit');

Route::get('/edit', 'RecordsController@showEdit');
```

**RecordsController.php**

```
public function showEdit()
{        
    $berita=Berita::all();   
    return view('editBerita')->with('berita',$berita);           
}

 public function edit($id_berita)
{
    $berita = Berita::find($id_berita);
    return View ('edit_form')->with('berita',$berita);  
}
```

**editberita.blade**

```
  @foreach($berita as  $key=>$berita)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$berita->id_berita}}</td>
        <td>{{$berita->judul_berita}}</td>
        <td>{{$berita->isi_berita}}</td>
        <td>{{$berita->tanggal_berita}}</td>
        <td>{{$berita->tanggal_postBerita}}</td>
        <td>{{$berita->tanggal_updateBerita}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('edit/' . $berita->id_berita) }}">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

**edit_form.blade**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/edited_data',$berita->id_berita) }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Judul:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='judul_berita' value="{{$berita->judul_berita}}"/> </br>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the error happened when I clicked on the edit button on editBerita.blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Berita model add `protected $primaryKey = 'berita_id';`

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot, I've been trying to find the mistake for 2 days cause I thought it was just a typo.

Comment: It sets the name you have used for primary key in the table. If you see in the Model class you are inheriting from you find that the default value is set there to id, which is why you did get the error that the id column is missing. Laravel is using this instead of using an extra query to the database to find what is set as primary key on the table